# SceneKit – Change object's opacity depending on how close it is to the camera

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I currently have 6 spheres that represent directions of x, -x, y, -y, z, -z and I would like to change the opacity of each SCNSphere to be 0 opacity when it is close to my camera and full transparency when it is far away.

```
struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var transparency: CGFloat = 0.5
    let sceneView = SCNView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) -> SCNView {
        
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let radius: Float = 0.75
        
        createSphere(x: 0, y: radius, z: 0)
        createSphere(x: 0, y: -radius, z: 0)
        createSphere(x: radius, y: 0, z: 0)
        createSphere(x: -radius, y: 0, z: 0)
        createSphere(x: 0, y: 0, z: radius)
        createSphere(x: 0, y: 0, z: -radius)
        
        return sceneView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) {
    }
    
    typealias UIViewType = SCNView
    
    func createSphere(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) {
        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
        sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
        sphere.firstMaterial?.transparency = transparency
        let spherenode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        spherenode.position = SCNVector3(x: x, y: y, z: z)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(spherenode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SceneKit to update any property at frame rate 60 fps you need to conform to `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocol and use its instance method called `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`.

Here's a code:

```
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: NSViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
    
    var scnView = SCNView()
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scene = SCNScene()
        scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.delegate = self               // SCNSceneRendererDelegate
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemIndigo
        
        sphereNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {

            let sphereTransform = self.sphereNode.simdTransform.columns.3
            let cameraTransform = (self.scnView.pointOfView?.simdTransform.columns.3)!
        
            self.sphereNode.opacity = CGFloat((simd_distance(sphereTransform, 
                                                             cameraTransform) / 5.0) - 0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or you can look at optional binding using `guard let` statement (UIKit example):

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var scnView: SCNView!
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scene = SCNScene()
        scnView.delegate = self               // SCNSceneRendererDelegate
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemIndigo
        
        sphereNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        let sphereTransform = self.sphereNode.simdTransform.columns.3
    
        guard let cameraTransform = self.scnView.pointOfView?.simdTransform.columns.3
        else { return }
    
        self.sphereNode.opacity = CGFloat((simd_distance(sphereTransform,
                                                         cameraTransform) / 5.0) - 0.5)
    }
}
```

Comment: why the asynchronous dispatch to the main queue? That isn't necessary and will introduce latency.

Comment: Hi @mnuages, Without asynchronous dispatch app crashes before opening with the following error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`. Try it if you wish.

Comment: maybe because of the force unwrapped optional?

Comment: Thank you for your help. In your example, how do I get the GameViewController to conform to NSObject?

Comment: @GavinJensen, just open a regular `Game` template for macOS in Xcode, delete the code in template and paste my code there.

Comment: Or you can use the code published here in iOS project. Instead of `scnView = self.view as! SCNView ` use `@IBOutlet var scnView: SCNView!`. And instead of NSClasses use UIClasses.

Comment: SceneKit macOS project allows you compile and debug much faster than iOS project. I've updated my answer.